# Sci-fi, mid-grade/YA novel about a girl in a wheelchair beta testing the world's first fully immersive VR program

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, virtual-worlds

I read this book when I was nine or ten, so back in the late 90s (no idea if it was new then, but probably based on the subject matter), and I really want to try to find it and recommend it if I can.

The main character (MC) was in an accident and confined to a wheelchair. In her despair, she became a bit of a recluse. Her father, a tech company CEO or something and programming genius invented the world's first fully immersive VR program. He gave his daughter and some random boy a copy to be the only beta testers (I don't think she knew he was the only one?).

The story goes as their friendship helps the MC come to terms with what happened and start living her life in the real world. Beyond that, I can't remember the climax or resolution to the story.

Anyway, thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Not "The Girl Who Was Plugged In" by James Tiptree, Jr.  but that was the first thing I thought of.

Comment: @Spencer - That wouldn't have been a bad answer, tbh

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is [*The Faces of Fear*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?31531) (1998) by Monica Hughes.  From a [review at *Qull and Quire*](https://quillandquire.com/review/the-faces-of-fear/):

> After **a car accident leaves 15-year-old Joan Sandow without the use of her legs**, Joan’s world looks pretty bleak. So when she and her Internet buddy, Steve (alias Whizkid), get a chance to **test a new virtual reality computer game**, Joan is thrilled. What they don’t know is that Jason, the game’s designer, has filled it with situations aimed at triggering their deepest, darkest fears. As they move through the four parts of the game, which involves finding four artifacts and saving the world from an asteroid, Jason’s malevolent plan backfires. Instead of succumbing to their fears, the two teens overcome them in the virtual world and bring their newfound confidence and sense of triumph back to their real lives.

[image: Cover of "The Faces of Fear" showing Joan and Steve in the alter-egos being attacked by a suit of armour]

I found a more extensive description in a review in the (now defunct) [Canadian Children's Literature Journal](https://ccl-lcj.ca/index.php/ccl-lcj), [Fall/Winter 1998](https://ccl-lcj.ca/index.php/ccl-lcj/issue/view/205).  The [review](https://ccl-lcj.ca/index.php/ccl-lcj/article/view/4510) (PDF download) says:

> Joan Sandow still suffers from nightmares about the **terrible car accident that left her legs paralyzed** and killed her mother. Unable to face the stares of other kids, **Joan has quit school and stays at home**, cared for by professionals but isolated in her misery. **Her father Max** is grieving too, but has allowed his daughter to build a cocoon around herself. Joan is desperately unhappy until she turns to cyberspace for her social life. In the world of the Internet she is no longer Joan but Joanna, a "warrior" persona with no physical limitations. There she meets the boy Whizkid, and their friendship soon involves playing Virtual Reality games, the most important of which is **a new experimental game designed in the lab of MaxCom Industries, Max's software company**.
>
> [...]
>
> Yet as the game progresses, both **Joan and Steve learn to face their fears**, and at the end are **able to meet and interact in real life** as themselves.